# Identify molex connector

Tags: pcb, connector, identification

Anyone know what kind of connector is this?
The female connector size is around 18x7 millimeters

[image: connector]
[image: connector]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Molex connector micro fit 3.0 family

https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/molex/0430251000/WM1787-ND/252500
https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/molex/0430451000/WM1817-ND/252530

Answer (score 4):

Looks like a Molex Micro-Fit. They should be on 3.0 mm centers.